# devcon restart not working on windows7

Tags: windows, device-manager, devcon

I am trying to run `devcon` command on windows7 as below but this is stuck forever,if I right-click on "scan for hardware changes" it is stuck aswell,how can I activate a COM port via commandline using devcon?is there a better way?

```
devcon.exe restart "@USB\VID_05C6&PID_9302&MI_01\6&1E2FC975&0&0001"
```

[image]

Comment: I would hazard a guess that this represents a bug in the relevant device driver.  But why are you trying to restart the driver anyway?  That shouldn't be necessary, especially if it is just a COM port.  Sounds like an XY problem, what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: the COM port  puts the device is downloadmode,any commands I send to this COM port doesnt work,only after a reboot of the full PC it works,so I am trying to find if there is a way just to restart the driver instead of the whole PC

Comment: You shouldn't need to reset the entire driver.  Try using the [IOCTL_SERIAL_RESET_DEVICE control code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff546671(v=vs.85).aspx) or perhaps one of the other control codes.  See also [Communications Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363196(v=vs.85).aspx), e.g., perhaps all you need to do is to call SetCommState which "reinitializes all hardware and control settings".

Comment: ... better still, check the documentation for the device that's attached to the COM port.  It should explain how to get the device out of download mode.

Comment: How do I send `IOCTL_SERIAL_RESET_DEVICE` request, is there a tool that takes these commmands....JFYI...issue is not about getting the device out of download mode...this COM port supports a variety of operations,it sort of becomes stuck after a while

Comment: You would have to write a program to send the I/O control request.  But it very much sounds like your problem is a buggy device driver or faulty hardware, so there might not be any way for you to fix this in software.

Comment: I dont think its a buggy device driver,it happens on multiple machines ,theres got to be a way to reset the driver without resetting the PC

Comment: Well, of course there is.  But you're already using it, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you checked the manufacturer's web site to make sure you're using the latest version of the driver?